# Will go and brush or Will go and will brush?

Tags: ellipsis, repetition

1. What's the difference between these?

> I will go to the bathroom and brush my teeth
>
> I will go to the bathroom and will brush my teeth

Perhaps one of these sentences is grammatically incorrect.

2. Which one is desirable to use in technical writing?

Comment: The extra *will* is a waste of space. You can even say "I will go and brush my teeth in the bathroom," but not ideal in technical writing.

Comment: Neither is _incorrect_, but everyone knows that we normally brush our teeth _in_ the bathroom. You would only use the second _will_ if you were talking about a completely different action.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Worse than that, you *could* "validly" repeat the subject as well as the auxiliary verb: *I will go to the bathroom and **I will** brush my teeth.* Note that it's logically impossible for the presence or absence of subject or auxiliary to affect the meaning of the utterance, but it's at least *feasible* that I might be planning to brush my teeth somewhere else. Consider *The phones ringing but I'm desperate for a pee. I will go to the bathroom and answer the phone when whoever it is rings back if it's important.* I don't plan on answering the phone while in the bathroom!

Comment: It can be even simpler: "I will (go and) brush my teeth". You don't need to explain common actions, such as "I will boil some water for the tea *in a kettle*" or "I will butter the bread *with a knife*."

Comment: Do you mean by *go to the bathroom* relocate oneself into the bathroom, or do you mean relieve oneself? You might wish to take care because, at least in the US, both meanings are completely idiomatic. One can even hear things like, “Oh no! The puppy has gone to the bathroom on my bedroom floor!”

Comment: ... you might say "I will go to the bathroom and brush my teeth" if, say, you were doing it in the kitchen and someone objected.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - I was doing a sociology course in the late 1970s and one of the books had a section about a housing project called Pruitt-Igoe, in St Louis. One resident, interviewed by a researcher, said she didn't like people off the street 'going to the bathroom in the stairwell'. For a little moment I thought that the stairwells had bathrooms provided by an enlightened city administration.

Comment: @Qwendr Jo It seems everyone is distracted by your example sentences and is ignoring your actual question. Consider replacing your example with a technical one, like, "*The piston will descend and (will) draw a mixture of fuel and gas into the cylinder*". Even better would be to use the actual words you're working with, if they're not confidential.

Comment: In what kind of technical writing would you find  "will go and"?